# How do I check if an object contains a byte array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm having an issue with the following code.

```
byte[] array = data as byte[]; // compile error - unable to use built-in conversion

if (array != null) { ...
```

I only want to assign the data to array variable if the data is actually a byte array.

Comment: Interesting. It's been nine years since I wrote this question, and the above code compiles fine in dotnet core. 
I guess things have improved since the Silverlight days. Progress!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try

```
if(data.GetType().Name == "Byte[]") 
{
    // assign to array
}
```

Comment: "Byte[]" 

Yep that would work too. fixed my problem by checking the type of an object.

Answer (score 18):

How about this:

```
byte[] array = new  byte[arrayLength];
if (array is byte[])
{
    // Your code
}
```

Comment: Best looking answer - also avoids typos.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as I asked this I realised that the type of data was not object.

Making it of type object (its coming in via a type converter in Silverlight) and it worked.